# How to call an external API between two Views in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, callback, xcode7

I am a newbie in iOS development. Now I need to develop a small app that calls another app with its API. There two Views A and B. The button on View A will call the API to open the external app and get a set of data, then the data will be shown on View B. I used to create a navigationView and call the API in "viewDidLoad" but didn't work. The main problem is that when the external app is open it will not jump back to my own app. What kind of method should I use to build the connection between the two views, and where should I call the API and how to jump back?

Thanks!

Comment: Explain it a little bit more. Do you want to access a third party API with your app? You don't need to open another app for it . You can learn how that works via this easy tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial.

Comment: Are you accessing a web API or launching another app via its uri on the device? If the latter then the ability to return to your app will depend on whether the app you are calling supports that return and you will need to register a uri for your app for the callback

Comment: Thank you for replying. I intend to access a third party API with my app. I used "openURL" to call the API to open the third party app to open camera to take photo and analyze the photo, then jump back to my app and feedback the information about the photo. Now, I can call the API and let the external app work, but I don't know how to jump back to my app after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The App you want to get data from must have some callback url set, that way it should work :)

Here you get all you need to know:

http://x-callback-url.com/

It's the way that popular apps like Drafts or LaunchCenter work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying! Now, I can use callback url to call the API and open the third party app. But I can't make it jump back to my app after that. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! :-) Just add the x-success and you should be ready to go!